# Write-Host - Lose new line formating

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
 $output=$(dir)
 Write-Host $output
```

The output I have is:

```
jboss-eap-5.1 jboss-eap-6.1 jboss-eap-6.1(2) Middleware Oracle TestSymlinksJboss TomcatA TomcatB Was7.0
```

Is there any way to have the normal output like this: echo $output

```
Directory: C:\Servers


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         9/18/2012  10:33 AM            jboss-eap-5.1
d----          5/9/2013   1:10 PM            jboss-eap-6.1
d----         8/22/2013  11:33 AM            jboss-eap-6.1(2)
d----         1/22/2013   2:29 PM            Middleware
d----         1/22/2013   2:25 PM            Oracle
d----          8/1/2013   2:43 PM            TestSymlinksJboss
d----          4/4/2013   4:25 PM            TomcatA
d----         7/22/2013   4:49 PM            TomcatB
d----        10/18/2012   3:00 PM            Was7.0
```

I use Write-Host inside a function (so I don't want to use echo )
Thanks for any reply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write-Host host does no formatting.  It just displays the strings (or objects by coercing them to string) that you provide.  Try this to get PowerShell to do some formatting for you:

```
Write-Host ($output | Out-String)
```

Comment: So quick ! Any exactly what I need. Thanks a lot !